# Can I insert image inside diagram in StarUML?

Tags: diagram, staruml

I must design a simple diagram of an architecture, like "network map".
Can I import and insert small image in a diagram? Which diagram you recommended me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO STARUML DOES NOT PERMIT YOU TO INSERT AND IMAGE IN THE DIAGRAM it only permits utf8 encoded files for your network map i would recommend you use DIA which is an other modeling app

Answer (score 0):

{"kind":"views","type":null,"data":[{"_type":"RectangleView","_id":"AAAAAAGOiuElxKkXyqE=","_parent":{"$ref":"AAAAAAGOiq4RWKiyWpQ="},"font":"Arial;13;0","left":160,"top":248,"width":16,"height":280}],"context":{"id":"AAAAAAGOiq4RWKiyWpQ=","type":"UMLSequenceDiagram","refs":[]}}

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.